# How does the map $X^2_{n}=X_{n-1}+2$ reach its two fixed points?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The map $$X_n^2=X_{n-1}+2~~~~~~~(1)$$ can represent a bounded sequence of numbers: $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4,X_5,...X_{\infty}$, which can be obtained by
$$X_n=\sqrt{X_{n-1}+2}.~~~(2)$$
Interestingly, by numerics for any initial value of $X_1$ real or non-real (complex), from (2) we get $X_{100}, X_{200},...,X_{\infty}=2.$ This can be justified by noting that if $n$ is very large and the sequence $X_n$ is bounded
then $X_{n-1}=X_{n}=x$, then asymptotically (1) becomes $x^2-x-2=0 \implies x=-1,2.$

But now the question is how would the fixed point $X_{\infty}=-1$ be 
reached?

Comment: Take $X_n=-\sqrt{X_{n-1}+2}$.

Comment: How about $$x=2\cos2t$$

Comment: @ Fabio Lucchini Yes, very true.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee ,not clear, please explain.